# Last number of iterator in python

Tags: python-3.x, iterator

How to edit the iterator giving also the last number in the sequence, please? I mean in general, not for such an easy sequence. Using < instead of == is not an option.

```
class P():
    def __init__(self, n0):
        self.n = n0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.n == 1:
            raise StopIteration
        num = self.n
        self.n = self.n // 2 if self.n % 2 == 0 else 3 * self.n + 1
        return num

nmax = 1000
PP = P(nmax)

PPP = []

for j in PP:
    PPP.append(j) 

print(PPP)
```

Current output:

[10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2]

Desired output:

[10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]

Comment: Not able to reproduce this....

Comment: desired output _is_ the output

Comment: I am sorry. I edited the question. What error do you obtain? The code works for me.

Comment: In general you should not use `==`, but `<` ?  (Or, but that is not a better solution `== 0`)

Comment: Yes, but my original sequence is ending 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4; thus, I need to stop that when n == 1 and include 1. I cannot choose a number that is <.

Comment: Your question is too different from your original problem..... 

Comment: But you forgot to edit the `Current output` and the `Desired output`...

Comment: I am sorry. It is done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244572/discussion-between-carly-and-luuk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a local variable in your class to determin how many time you have get a next one:

```
class P():
    i = 0
    def __init__(self, n0):
        self.i=n0-1
        self.n = n0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        self.i=self.i-1
        if self.i == 1:
            raise StopIteration
        num = self.n
        self.n = self.n // 2 if self.n % 2 == 0 else 3 * self.n + 1
        return num

nmax = 10
PP = P(nmax)

PPP = []

for j in PP:
    PPP.append(j) 

print(PPP)
```

NOTE: Generally it is safer to write: `if self.i <= 1:` then `if self.i == 1:`. In some future change you might change the value of `i`, and start decrementing it with 2, adn then the `==` variant will fail.

EDIT: When you want to stop when the previous value equals to `1`, you can do:

```
class P():
    previous_value = 0
    def __init__(self, n0):
        self.i=n0-1
        self.n = n0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.previous_value == 1:
            raise StopIteration
        num = self.n
        self.n = self.n // 2 if self.n % 2 == 0 else 3 * self.n + 1
        self.previous_value = num
        return num

nmax = 20
PP = P(nmax)

PPP = []

for j in PP:
    PPP.append(j) 

print(PPP)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work for greater numbers, for instance, nmax = 1000.

Comment: "but it does not work" what does not work? are you getting an error? (My crystal ball is not working.....)

Comment: The sequence ends with [5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1,....]

Comment: Also note that in your question, you have `nmax=10`, which will output 7 variables. (which is 3 less than the value of nmax)  So, when you specify `nmax=1000`, a total of (1000-3)=997 items will be shown.

Comment: And is it possible to do that without specifying the number of items in output?

Comment: You have to explain (preferably in words) when this should stop.

Comment: The stop should be 1, but I need to include 1 in a list. Now 1 is not included.